# How to add separators between different numbers of children node values, for each parent node in Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

Any ideas if this is possible in PHP **DOMXPath**: I have for example 3 parent spans, and random number of children within each. First I was collecting data like this:
"`//span[@class='parent']`" and getting the node-value which was something like "`Child TextChildText2Child Text 3`" for the first item.

However I'm trying to get something like "`Child Text,ChildText2,Child Text 3`" with the comma separator.

Any ideas? I want to be able to identify which children belong to which parent as at the same time I am collecting other data within the parents:

```
<span class="parent">Parent 1
    <span class="child">Child Text</span>
    <span class="child">ChildText2</span>
    <span class="child">Child Text 3</span>
</span>
<span class="parent">Parent 2
    <span class="child">Child Text4</span>
    <span class="child">ChildText5</span>

</span>
<span class="parent">Parent 3
    <span class="child">Child Text6</span>
    <span class="child">Child Text7</span>
    <span class="child">ChildText8</span>
    <span class="child">Child Text 9</span>
</span>
```

The following PHP is what I am currently using:

```
$array  = [];
$result = $xpath->query("//span[@class='parent']");
for ($x=0; $x<$result->length; $x++){
    $array[$x]['children'] = trim($result->item($x)->nodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in PHP directly instead of trying to get too fancy with the xpath itself. Just throw the node values into an array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it with a comma as the separator.

---

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@class="parent"]') as $parent) {
    $childText = [];
    foreach ($xpath->query('span[@class="child"]', $parent) as $child) {
        $childText[] = trim($child->nodeValue);
    }
    echo implode(',', $childText), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
Child Text,ChildText2,Child Text 3
Child Text4,ChildText5
Child Text6,Child Text7,ChildText8,Child Text 9
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. Will use this. Just a quick one, my array doesnt seem to clear with $childtext = []; it keeps adding the results together... so i added in a counter and wrote to $childtext[$x] = ..

Comment: All sorted, had a variable of childtext instead of childText :S

Answer (score 1):

Using xpath > 2:

```
'string-join(//span[@class="parent"]/span, ",")'
```

### Output:

```
Child Text,ChildText2,Child Text 3,Child Text4,ChildText5,Child Text6,Child Text7,ChildText8,Child Text 9
```

Comment: Thanks awesome, but from there how do I differentiate between each parent? For example: Child Text,ChildText2,Child Text 3 belong to parent[1], so i would like that string i supposed saved into the array[1], then array[2] would be "Child Text4,ChildText5"

Comment: If you talk about array, we need to know your programming language

Comment: Okay, well im using PHP with DOMXPath. Maybe its as simple as using DOMDocument instead and doing a loop through the children.

Comment: PHP has xpath 1.0 only. So you won't get this to the run as-is.